# includegraphics not working

Tags: graphics, texlive, texlive-2019

`\includegraphics` is not working with `TeX Live`. The minimal code included in the file ´test.tex` is the following

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{electro1.eps}
\end{document}
```

(electro1.eps is present in the directory).

Compiling the file `test.tex`I get the error

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
> (preloaded format=latex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering
> extended mode (./test.tex LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2 L3
> programming layer <2020-02-14> (./article.cls Document Class: article
> 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (./inputenc.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
> (./graphicx.sty (./keyval.sty) (./graphics.sty (./trig.sty)
> (./graphics.cfg)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
> (./test.aux)) Runaway argument? "electro1.eps" \edef \Gin@ext
> {\Gin@sepdefault \filename@ext }\ifx \Gin@ext \ET C. ! File ended
> while scanning use of @tempa. 
> \par  <*> test.tex
> ?

The log file does not give more information.

I have reinstalled `TeX Live`, but nothing changes. I am running Linux Mint 20 Ulyana with Linux 5.4.0-48-generic kernel. The texlive-base version is 2019.20200218-1.

Comment: Why aris inputinc, graphicx, key-val, graphics etc coming from the same folder? Please test in a folder which nly contains your tex file and the eps such that you're using the package versions from your installation

Comment: You're right! These .sty files were already in the folder I was using (I uploaded it from a colleague). I was messing up different versions of latex. Thanks!

Comment: And now you know another tool to use for debugging things like this.